# A special base64 implementation in Go/Golang (like in Drupal's PhpassHashedPassword::base64Encode())

Tags: go, drupal, base64, phpass

I have tried to implement a Drupal compatible authentication in Go and use this package for base64 encoding: [golang.org/src/encoding/base64/base64.go](https://golang.org/src/encoding/base64/base64.go)

The Result: the created and in Drupal saved hashes don't matches. Only after reimplementing Go's base64-package, where I do the bit shifting like in Drupals base64Encode() the hashes matched:

```
input bit location:                 abcdefgh ijklmnop qrstuvwx
Go's base64.go bit location:        ..abcdef ..ghijkl ..mnopqr ..stuvwx
PHP's base64Encode() bit location:  ..cdefgh ..mnopab ..wxijkl ..qrstuv
```

Well, I do instead of Google's implementation:

```
...

for si < n {
            // Convert 3x 8bit source bytes into 4 bytes
            val := uint(src[si+0])<<16 | uint(src[si+1])<<8 | uint(src[si+2])

            dst[di+0] = enc.encode[val>>18&0x3F]
            dst[di+1] = enc.encode[val>>12&0x3F]
            dst[di+2] = enc.encode[val>>6&0x3F]
            dst[di+3] = enc.encode[val&0x3F]

            si += 3
            di += 4
        }

...
```

my own implementation now with behalf of Drupal's base64Encode()

```
...

for si < n {
        // Convert 3x 8bit source bytes into 4 bytes
        // val := uint(src[si+0])<<16 | uint(src[si+1])<<8 | uint(src[si+2])
        val := uint(src[si+0]) | uint(src[si+1])<<8 | uint(src[si+2])<<16

        dst[di+0] = enc.encode[val&0x3F] 
        dst[di+1] = enc.encode[val>>6&0x3F]
        dst[di+2] = enc.encode[val>>12&0x3F]
        dst[di+3] = enc.encode[val>>18&0x3F]

        si += 3
        di += 4
    }

...
```

My Questions:

- is already there in Go an implementation like I did (reimplemented
  Drupal's base64Encode())?
- does this special base64 encoding have a name? Are there Literature/Publication references?

Comment: Which go base64 encoding did you use? There are four standards: Standard encoding or URL encoding, with our without padding. My guess is one of these will match what you want.

Comment: Drupal's implementation is from [Portable PHP password hashing framework](https://www.openwall.com/phpass/). If you go to their site and download, you'll find some C code that might be easier to port to GO.

Comment: Can you tell us about the actual authentication problem [X] instead of this bizarre encoding problem that you think is happening? [Y] http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @ChrisHaas it's really just a wrapper around [crypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)), and I'd find it hard to believe if Go didn't have something for that already. The only sticking point might be if the PHP side is using the new Argon hashing.

Comment: The hashing part is, but the bas64 encoding is native. I honestly don't know why a custom base64 function is needed except that framework used to support PHP 3. I agree  that this is probably xy problem.

Comment: Just because I'm curious, I see that Go does support custom alphabets using [`NewEncoding`](https://golang.org/src/encoding/base64/base64.go?s=14795:14848), should be pretty straight forward. The OP would be targetting crypt's radix-64 format for the `/etc/password` file that uses the alphabet `./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

Comment: My issue is NOT about a special alphabet. Yes, I can set a custom alphabet. That's not the point. The bit shifting implementations used in phpass and in Go's golang.org/src/encoding/base64/base64.go are different.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I posted im my question which base64 I mean: golang.org/src/encoding/base64/base64.go

Comment: @ChrisHaas thank you! I already ported the PHP's implementation. But I hope there is a Googles official implementation. I just didn't found something like this.

Comment: @Sammitch the actual problem is: if one try to implement an authentication to the Drupal (8) database (hashes saved by Drupal) and use the same hashing algorithm (sha512), nevertheless the matching fails. And I found it out, it fails just because of different Base64 implementation. The different implementation in Drupal and in Go. I could reimplement the Drupals way (phpass) to Base64 encode, but I want to know now, is there really no implementation of phpass's Base64 done by Google? So I will publish my implementation.